# My board works intermittently... when I short some pins

Tags: microcontroller, breadboard

I'm trying to get an I2C bus working. I'm using a PIC24FJ32GA002 micro. At the moment it's not connected to any other devices. It doesn't work. I then run a screwdriver along the pins of the MCU and it starts working. Power cycle and it's not working, same trick with the screwdriver and it starts working. The most confusing thing is I do not need to hold the screwdriver there - simply running it across the pins once or twice is enough to get it working.

The software is basic, just an infinite loop sending out I2C data. What could be wrong? It's on a breadboard. I'm beginning to suspect a faulty connection, but what about a breadboard would cause it to stop working after power is reset?

Comment: Hmm I've been reading the datasheet in some more depth and it looks like I might need a cap on MCLR. (because the power supply doesn't rise instantly, the chip needs to be held in reset briefly.) I'll have to jumper this for programming, although the transition may be sharp enough for the PICkit 2 or PIC to not care. If this is the problem, I'm unsure on why it isn't affecting the dsPIC.

Comment: Interesting -- I'm using a PIC24FJ256GB110 and wasn't aware of the cap.  Turns out Microchip has put out a newer version of the datasheet for the PIC24FJ256GB110 than I had, which includes a new section on the MCLR pin.  Board rev time.

Comment: @tcrosley: It probably only applies for situations like mine where I have a linear reg and two 470u caps (for bulk filtering as my power supply is a bit touchy.)

Comment: What clock are you using? (see Peter Gibson's answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! I think I fixed it!

And I learned some things about my MCU in the process.

I2C is not working properly because of a [chip errata](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/80470e.pdf). Item 10.

```
Module: I2C™ (I2C1, SDA Line State)

When using I2C1, the SDA1 line state may not be
detected properly unless it is first held low for
150 ns after enabling the I2C module.

In Master mode, this error may cause a bus collision
to occur instead of a Start bit transmission.
Transmissions after the SDA1 pin has been held
low will occur correctly.

In Slave mode, the device may not Acknowledge
the first packet sent after enabling the I2C module.
In this case, it will return a NACK instead of an
ACK. The device will correctly respond to packets
after detecting a low level on the line for 150 ns.

The I2C2 module operates as expected and does
not exhibit this issue.
```

This explains why the screwdriver trick works. I was shorting SDA to Vss when I ran the screwdriver along the pins, which allowed the module to start correctly. It only affects A3/A4 silicon.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a checklist - useful to anyone with this kind of problem.

- Do you have pullups on both of your I2C lines?

In an I2C bus, both clock and data lines float, so they can be driven by any device on the chain. An I2C bus needs 2 pullup resistors.

- Have you checked your I2C signals on an oscilloscope?

Are the edges clean, are the timings right?

- Is your microcontroller connected up correctly?

Is reset tied? are all power and ground pins connected up?

- Do you have enough bypass caps?

Is your power supply clean?

- Is your I2C running at a sane speed?

Breadboards and high speed signals don't mix.

Comment: 4.7k on both to 3.3V.

Comment: The I2C line isn't connected to anything except two scope probes going to my oscilloscope.

Comment: @Thom: If nothing is there to send ACKs it may cause problems

Comment: Does it work if you disconnect the scope probes?

Comment: I swapped to using 1.2k (closest to 1k I had on hand) and the edge transitions are sharper but it still won't work until I run the screwdriver along the pins.

Comment: Which pin in particular makes it work? What does that tell you?

Comment: @Joby Taffey I'm unsure. I suspect it's either the SCL/SDA pair or PGEC3/INT0.

Comment: @Joby Taffey, If I disconnect the scope probes I'm acting blind. How do I know if it works then?

Comment: If it were INT0 - I'd go look at my ISRs, if it were SCL/SDA I'd look at how my I2C driver handles ACK/NAK timeouts

Comment: @Joby Taffey The code is very basic and has no interrupts and just continuously polls the I2C peripheral until it is ready to receive or send data.

Comment: If the pin in question was SCL/SDA, I'd look carefully at my I2C driver

Comment: I agree with joby, i'm betting your not handling NACK properly at some point in the driver.

Comment: @Mark, this is probably correct - I narrowed it down to an infinite loop somewhere, which was waiting forever for some event. I'm trying to figure out how to fix it now.

Answer (score 2):

That PIC24 might not work properly on a breadboard. Good decoupling of all supply pins is essential with the 16-bit PICs, which would be difficult to achieve.

Comment: Heck, I'm already running a 40 MIPS dsPIC33F with no problems. It runs my software OSD slightly over clocked at 41.5 MIPS. This is a tiny 16 MIPS 24F device. All Vdd/Vss pins have 100n caps.

Comment: There might be differences between chips, the dsPIC might just happen to be more tolerant of poor layout. I always use PCBs.

Comment: @Leon Heller, I suppose so. But that doesn't help me because I can't afford to prototype a PCB for every design. Maybe you can, but I can't. Any ideas on how to get it working with a breadboard?

Comment: The 24F has *virtually* the same layout as the dsPIC with regards to pin placement. They are essentially pin compatible, but one is of course less powerful.

Comment: I make my own PCBs for simple circuits and never have problems like that. It only takes about an hour.

Comment: @Leon, I considered doing this but it's pretty tricky to do PCBs at home, I don't have the capital to invest in them, so I just use a breadboard. I'm not going to drop £200 and start making PCBs at home. I don't have the money.

Comment: It cost me a lot less than that.

Comment: @Leon Heller, I need a PCB drill+xformer+stand = £60, UV exposure unit = £120, ferric chloride = £20, it all adds up! Either way I'm happy with breadboards and for the foreseeable future I don't see me changing. I will be producing the final product on a PCB.

Comment: prototyping on PCB is valuable. Hope you can get into it soon.

Answer (score 2):

> I then run a screwdriver along the pins of the MCU and it starts working.

Do you mean that the I2C part starts working, or the MCU? Flash an LED during startup to show if the microcontroller is running or not.

Assuming you're not shorting adjacent pins together, then the screwdriver is probably introducing a small capacitance as it touches the pins. This may be stabilising the oscillator source enough to allow the MCU to start up.

If you're using an external crystal oscillator, make sure that you've got the appropriate load capacitors connected (usually in the order of 20pF). Sometimes it will work without the caps (especially on breadboards which introduce a small capacitance), but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: 20 pF, not 20 nF!

Comment: Heh, whoops. I was thinking pF as I typed that.. Corrected thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All VDD and VSS pins connected appropriately, including VDDCORE?  ENVREG tied high or low?  MCLR pulled up?

Comment: ENVREG grounded, VDDCORE has 10u/25V tant. bead, 100n caps on both Vdd/Vss pairs. MCLR thru 4.7k, and to PICkit 2.

Comment: For now, I would replace the I2C code with a simple loop that slowly toggles an LED and see if that works (or fails in the same way).